# Avoid VerifyError overriding a method in older APIs

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm trying to be notified when signal strength changes on Android. My application supports all the way back to Android 1.5 (API level 3), so I need something that will work for old and new APIs.

Android 1.5 defines the `PhoneStateListener` which is also available in the newest API versions. However, the old `onSignalStrength` changed method is deprecated and replaced with a newer method, `onSignalsStrengthChanged` which defines a signature accepting a single `SignalStrength` instance as its parameter. Unfortunately `SignalStrength` doesn't exist in API levels before 7.

How can I override this new method in my code without incurring a `VerifyError` on older versions of Android? Can I use Reflection to optionally override a method in a class based on some condition?